# Wiring for 120 now with 240 option later?

Tags: electrical-panel, 120-240v

I want to wire a dedicated plugin to the front of my garage for a new EV, which at the moment needs to be 120.  But later, I may upgrade to a 240 based charger.

Is there a suggested way I could wire this up to give myself flexibility in the future to convert to 240 without running new wire?  Like run 3 (hot -hot - ground) and just use one hot for now, and the second later for 220?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Run all four wires

Run a /3 cable (hot, hot, neutral, ground) to the receptacle location.  For 110, you cap off a hot, and use the other hot, the neutral, and the ground for the receptacle.  For 220, you can cap off the neutral and have 2 hots and a ground for a NEMA 6.  If you want 110 & 220 together at some point, you can then land all four wires on a NEMA 14.

I'd run this circuit using 6/3 by the way -- that allows you to have anything up to a NEMA 14-50 there with an appropriate breaker to match.

Comment: 14-50 would make sense.  I also have noticed that there are 220 to 110 adapters (like https://www.amazon.com/AC-WORKS-AD1430520-Household-Connector/dp/B0778XN2Q7/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1514092427&sr=8-2&keywords=gas+range+adapter) - so I could wire up for 220 and use one of them in the mean time.

Comment: @TimHolt -- I'd pigtail in the 110 receptacle for now and put the right-sized breaker for the receptacle you use in.  The wire can be fatter without an issue (you'll just need pigtails to attach a 15 or 20A receptacle to the fat wires)

Comment: @TimHolt You will find that cheater block is not UL listed... or if listed, the listing is a forgery.  Dodgy places like eBay, AliBaba and Amazon *Marketplace* will happily sell you anything, legal, safe or not.

Comment: @TimHolt For the most flexibility I would install a subpanel.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible wiring modes in North American split-phase wiring:

- 120V only: One hot, neutral, and ground.   (/2 plus ground)
- 240V only: one hot, the other hot, and ground, no neutral.  (/2 plus ground)
- 240V/120V: both hots, and neutral, and ground.  (/3 plus ground)

Note the same /2 cable is used in both of the first examples.  Just the white wire is marked with tape to mark it as a "hot", and the wires are landed on a 240V breaker not a 120V.  So if you are 100% confident that your future 240V chargers will be 240V-*only*, you could get away with /2 cable.

Unfortunately I am aware that some chargers are not.  I don't know what's wrong with those builders, the bits they need 120V for could easily be made to work on 240V, and then the charger could be marketed worldwide. SMH...

### But there's another way

You could bring out 6/3 cable out to a subpanel, giving you 240/120V split at the subpanel. Very standard stuff.  Then, add a breaker and receptacle for whcihever charger you get, when you get it.  The general idea is, you're only going to be charging one EV at a time. So if you have a 30A charger and a 50A charger, you only need to provision 50A of service, not 80A.

The same logic applies when bringing power out to a single RV parking/camp site.  You can provision all of 240/50, 240/30, 120/30 and 120/20, knowing that an RV will only use one of them at a time.

Comment: Can you give us full electrical specifications on both of the units considered? I think that some of the options listed above could involve considerable unnecessary expense.

Comment: @PaulLogan How can the person provide "full electrical specifications" for a future charger that may not even exist yet?  *Of course* the subpanel will cost more; the benefit is versatility and fallback (e.g. if the big charger goes on the blink you can just use the little charger; you don't need to rewire the works.)